# PHP session resets on refresh

Tags: php, session

I've been trying to search online for possible answers to this question, but I really can't figure it out. There are many people with a similar problem, but mine has a unique touch to it that I don't understand, nor have I encountered it anywhere else.

I created a login system that worked fine. However, I wanted to make it more secure, so I used this tutorial: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL. I can still login, but whenever I refresh my page, I automatically log out. After I while I figured out that the session ID changes.

The curious thing is this, when I call var_dump($_SESSION); on the 3rd line of my code (directly after session_start();), the session ID remains the same, and everything works. As soon as I comment this line, the problem returns.

I do regenerate the session ID using the following code:

```
$session_name = 'robinator123';   // Set a custom session name
$secure = FALSE;
// This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
$httponly = true;
// Forces sessions to only use cookies.
if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
    header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
    exit();
}
// Gets current cookies params.
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
    $cookieParams["path"], 
    $cookieParams["domain"], 
    $secure,
    $httponly);
// Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_name($session_name);
session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id(true);    // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
```

When I call the var_dump($_SESSION);, the regeneration fails because the headers have already been sent by the var_dump. However, when I replace var_dump with a normal echo statement the headers also fail, but the session ID still changes. I have no idea what's going on.

A few notes:

- I did not forget to call session_start(); at the beginning of my code
- the included php code that I use to store session variables is located outside my web root, but the problem isn't solved if I place those back into my root, so I'm guessing that can't be the problem.

Comment: remove the `session_regenerate_id(true)` You do not want to regenerate the session id. let php handle all session id stuff. What you should have is a `$_SESSION['myid']` that holds the key to the database item you want.

Comment: Thanks, but according to the tutorial I refer to, it is safer to regenerate the session ID; "Also the "session_regenerate_id()" function, which regenerates the session id on every page reload, helps prevent session hijacking.". Is this true, or is it better not to regenerate?

Comment: Well look at it this way... User request: give me that page. your site: Okay visitor aeb123. visitor. okay im aeb123 to you. your site. nah man, I'll call you dude123. next request. Hello site, im aeb123. your site I dont know any aeb123. I only know dude123.  To protect against session hijacking use long session id's. they are harder to bruteforce in time before the session expires. Couple this with a flood protection that throttles a user if he makes more than 100 requests  a minute to the same page you have pretty decent protection.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets You don't need to brute force a session hijack. XSS is one attack vector which can very easily give you a clients cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved the problem by editing the regeneration piece of code. Removing the regeneration didn't work, but I fixed it by setting the parameters I had forgotten to change (i.e. lifetime, path, and domain), and by removing the parameter "true" from the session_regenerate_id(); command (I literally copy-pasted this code from the tutorial, and failed to notice these things when I was making all the changes).

However, I'm still very curious how var_dump was able to avoid the problem..